# Size of class vs. size of enclosing template class

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

Consider the code below:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
};

template <class T>
class Bar
{
    T t;
};
```

Is it guaranteed that `sizeof(Foo) == sizeof(Bar<Foo>)` always evaluates to `true` across any standard C++ compiler?

Are there any situations in which the above condition would never be true?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you care?

Comment: And why would you do that?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Curiosity. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the standard makes that guarantee - an implementation is free to add padding at the end of `Bar`.

But it's hard to see why any real implementation would add padding at the end of `Bar` but not `Foo`. Unless, say, `Foo` was explicitly given some non-default alignment (e.g. byte aligned); `Bar` would then be padded to the default alignment.

Comment: This is more or less what I want to find out: "I don't believe the standard makes that guarantee".

Comment: @Zeenobit I  explained why.